# Will I have issues obtaining an Indian visa as a Pakistani-American?

Tags: visas, india, us-citizens, pakistan

I think the title sums it up pretty well but I am planning on travelling to India for a friend's wedding in January and wanted to know if I would have any issues obtaining a visa. This might be an odd question but with the tensions in the region over the past year I want to see if I should lower the expectations of my friend who is very excited to have me attend his wedding. For context, I was born and raised in the United States and have just this year gone to Pakistan for the very first time in my life but my immediate and extended family all live in Pakistan.

I understand that similar questions have been asked but with the very recent issues between Pakistan and India I thought it would be okay to ask again.

How likely or unlikely am I to have my visa denied?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I'm not a dual citizen, just a citizen of the US

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that the Indian visa process is **considerably more complicated and time consuming** if you are of Pakistani descent, but you are **unlikely to be denied the visa** if everything checks out.  I don't believe the government publishes visa rejection rates though, so this is anecdotal.

If you're looking to go in January, I would advise you to apply *immediately*, since processing can take 2-3 months: http://www.indianembassy.nl/eoi.php?id=Visa-Pakistani